# PL/SQL Comparison error in trigger (PLS-00405)

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to make a simple trigger which would have to check the given values on insert and update. I have to check that ID has to different of NAVAZUJE_NA (Foreign key referencing ID). Here's the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PREDMETY_INSERT_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PREDMETY 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.ID = :NEW.NAVAZUJE_NA THEN --There is an error (PLS-00405) 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Predmet nemuze navazovat sam na sebe.', FALSE);
  ELSIF :NEW.NAVAZUJE_NA > (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM PREDMETY) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Predmet nemuze navazovat na neexistujici predmet.', FALSE);
  ELSIF :NEW.ID < 0 OR :NEW.NAVAZUJE_NA < 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Neplatny index predmetu nebo predmetu, na ktery ma dany predmet navazovat.', FALSE);
  END IF;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('[ERROR] '||sqlerrm);
END;
```

Thanks for any solution.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements.  In general, a row-level trigger on a table cannot query that table.  So you can't run `select max(id) from predmety` in a row-level trigger on `predmety`.  You also can't put a query in an `IF` clause that way-- you'd need a separate variable that was populated before the `IF` statement.  And throwing exceptions only to catch them and try to print them to `dbms_output` is very, very unlikely to be reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, solved. Printing errors to `dbms_output` is only for academic purpose.

Comment: @Justin Cave actually you can run select max(id) into variable from table in row-level trigger, this works. It' won't work with queries returning more rows

Comment: @Mina - The problem is not the number of rows the query will return.  The problem is that you can't query table `A` in a row-level trigger on table `A` in general.  Yes, if you are only allowing `INSERT` operations and if every `INSERT` is a single-row `INSERT ... VALUES`, it will work.  But that is a rather severe restriction to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when you fetch max id into variable and use variable in your if statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PREDMETY_INSERT_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PREDMETY 
FOR EACH ROW
declare 
c number;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(ID) into c FROM PREDMETY;
  IF :NEW.ID = :NEW.NAVAZUJE_NA THEN --There is an error (PLS-00405) 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Predmet nemuze navazovat sam na sebe.', FALSE);
  ELSIF :NEW.NAVAZUJE_NA > c THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Predmet nemuze navazovat na neexistujici predmet.', FALSE);
  ELSIF :NEW.ID < 0 OR :NEW.NAVAZUJE_NA < 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Neplatny index predmetu nebo predmetu, na ktery ma dany predmet navazovat.', FALSE);
  END IF;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('[ERROR] '||sqlerrm);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 11g or 12c you can write a compound trigger. It has a section that executes before the actual triggering activity starts. That is, you can read from the table in that section because this is before the table enters a mutating state:

```
create or replace trigger Predmety_Ciu
For Insert Or Update On Predmety
Compound Trigger
    MaxID   int;

    Before Statement Is Begin
        -- Be prepared this might be the first record written to the table
        select nvl( max( ID ), 0 ) into MaxID from Predmety;
    End Before Statement;

    Before Each Row Is Begin
      IF :NEW.ID = :NEW.NAVAZUJE_NA THEN --There is an error (PLS-00405) 
        Raise_Application_Error(-20000, 'Predmet nemuze navazovat sam na sebe.', False);
      Elsif :New.Navazuje_Na > Maxid Then
        Raise_Application_Error(-20001, 'Predmet nemuze navazovat na neexistujici predmet. Další objekt ID: ' || to_char( Maxid ), False);
      Elsif :New.Id < 0 Or :New.Navazuje_Na < 0 Then
        Raise_Application_Error(-20002, 'Neplatny index predmetu nebo predmetu, na ktery ma dany predmet navazovat.', False);
      End If;
    End Before Each Row;

    After Each Row Is Begin
        -- Vložte nějaký kód, který chcete spustit po vložení řádku
        If Inserting Then
            Maxid := Maxid + 1;
        end if;
    End After Each Row;

    After Statement Is Begin
        Null; -- Vložte nejaký kód, který chcete spustit po zadání všech rádek.
    End After Statement;
End Predmety_Ciu;
```

I removed the exception handler because I wanted the exceptions.