# ORA-04079:invalid trigger specification

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

```
create or replace trigger fineCalc
AFTER UPDATE ON book_issue
for each row
when ((new.date_of_return-old.date_of_issue)>7) 
declare 
  rcpt_no  number;
  s_id  char(10);
begin
  if :old.card_id in (select card_id from STUDENT_BOOK_ISSUE)
  then
    select max(receipt_no) into rcpt_no from fine;
    select student_id into s_id from STUDENT_BOOK_ISSUE sbi where sbi.card_id=:old.card_id;

    insert into fine values( rcpt_no+1,((:NEW.date_of_return-:OLD.date_of_issue-7)*5),s_id);
  end if;
end;
```

This gets ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification in Apex's SQL Workshop:

[image: Oracle Apex screenshot]

How can I fix it?

Comment: That gets PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context, not ORA-04079. You can't have a subquery as part of an `if`, [you need to get the query result into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29134619/266304). Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Showing the actual code you're running and the error you get would be a good start.

Comment: i am performing the trigger operation in oracle 11g....then it is showing ORA:04079 error while on oracle SQL Developer its showing PLS-00405:Subquery not allowed in this context.....what should i do now

Comment: Not relevant to the error, but using `max(receipt_no)` isn't a good idea; it's [better to use a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17210835/266304).

Comment: Where are you seeing the ORA-04079? Are you sure that isn't still just on screen from an earlier compilation attempt? You seem to suggest "in oracle 11g" means a different client to SQL Developer, but that's the database version. If you're getting different behaviour in two clients then tell us what they both are, including the versions you're using.

Comment: i am sure that i am still getting same error .....if there is way to send screen shot i'll surely send it...

Comment: i am using SQL DEVELOPER version 4.1.3.20 ..

Comment: Open a new window. And run the code again. If you see error, take screenshot and attach (edit the question, there you will see option to attach)

Comment: i am getting PLS-00405 error on SQL developer...and ORA-04079 on oracle 11g...pls give me solution for Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex suggested, move the `if` condition outside and try again.

```
create or replace trigger fineCalc
AFTER UPDATE ON book_issue
for each row
when ((new.date_of_return-old.date_of_issue)>7) 
declare 
  rcpt_no  number;
  s_id  char(10);
  v_count number;
begin
  select count(*) into v_count from STUDENT_BOOK_ISSUE where card_id=:old.card_id;
  if v_count > 0
  then
    select max(receipt_no) into rcpt_no from fine;
    select student_id into s_id from STUDENT_BOOK_ISSUE sbi where sbi.card_id=:old.card_id;
    insert into fine values( rcpt_no+1,((:NEW.date_of_return-:OLD.date_of_issue-7)*5),s_id);
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry the `begin` clause wasnt at right place. Thanks @alex from correcting it.
@abhishekjadhavpatil - Try the updated answer and check again.

Comment: there is no underscore between book and issue on second line. And there is no `;` after line 13 after `fine`. Looks like you didn't copy the code which was given in answer. Fix it.

Comment: i have made changes according to suggestion but still i am getting same error.

Comment: thanks Alex and Utsav....my trigger is created and updating database successfully